# insert no cumple su función

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy intentando usar el `.insert` para poder, insertar un texto en un widget de tipo `text`, el tema es que no funciona y simplemente la caja de texto se mantiene vacía.

```
for data in lectura:
   idd_text.set(data[0])
   comentarioss.insert(INSERT, data[4])
```

También probé con `(1.0, data[2])` y nada.

Comment: Dos cosas pueden estar pasando: O el bucle for no se está ejecutando por que lectura es un iterable vacío, o data[4] es una cadena vacía, por lo que no hay nada que insertar.

Comment: Hola Estimado Kaster, un gusto en saludar, podrías publicar los datos de origen y el error que te arroja con tu código? y el resultado esperado per un mejor análisis de la problemática.  saludos

Comment: es "insert" ó "1.0" es un valor de cadena.

Comment: @tincopasan si el OP hace en alguna parte from tkinter import *, entonces es muy probable que INSERT sea una constante que vale "insert".

Comment: @DanteS. si el OP no lo muestra en el código que pone, no me gusta suponer que lo puede estar haciendo, si bien tu comentario es valedero, también estás adivinando que lo haya declarado. Además puso probé con (1.0 etc.